# AngularJS | Conditional Class using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm wanting to apply a conditional class to an element on the page.

Currently it's working with the following code:

```
ng-class="{ 'vfnz-form--error' : loginForm.username.$invalid  }
```

This applies a invalid class if the input field is invalid. I'm wanting to apply a "**valid"** class when the user input field is valid.

Is this possible to achieve in the same line of code?

Here is a fiddle example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/14/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do it in many ways, one simple way would be to use an object with bracket notation.

Example:-

```
ng-class="{ true: 'vfnz-form--error', false : 'vfnz-form--good'  }[loginForm.username.$invalid]"
```

Or (since it cannot be both invalid and valid):-

```
ng-class="{'vfnz-form--error' : loginForm.username.$invalid, 'vfnz-form--good' : loginForm.username.$valid}"
```

And if you want to do it only if form is dirty you could yes add condition to check for $pristine/$dirty but you could also make use of the class angular adds on the inputs (and on the form as well) i.e `ng-pristine/ng-dirty` so you could define the rule with these class names to make it more specific.

ex:-

```
.vfnz-form--error .ng-dirty.something{/*apply bad rules*/}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, the only thing is the field onload is set to invalid without a user inputting a value. Does this need to check for $pristine?

Comment: Yes, you could check for $dirty, basically you could have your css rule itself define that.

Comment: Can I do this by adding && !loginForm.username.$dirty ?

Comment: This is correct: { 'vfnz-form--error' : loginForm.username.$invalid && !loginForm.username.$pristine, 'vfnz-form--valid' : loginForm.username.$valid }

Comment: Yes it should be, Actually i am not able to open your fiddle. :( Infact what i am saying is angular adds a class `ng-dirty` to the input you can actually have your css rules written accordingly instead of adding one more condition in ng-class. i.e .vfnz-form--error .ng-dirty.something{/*apply bad rules*/}

Comment: what "is" that first example? Never seen this sintax "{ ... }[value]"