# Angular.js How to insert css class on click and to remove all others

Tags: angularjs

I'm applying two css classes onto my html, when I click on my span element.

right now I have a border and looks fine, I want keep this.

but:
so If I click in the Icon  I said in the icon `<i>` the Icon color change for blue.

but I don't want remove the functionality of the span who contains the border.

thanks.

html + angular

```
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <br>
    <i ng-class='{"gamepad-red":tog==1}' class="fa fa-lg fa-gamepad"></i>
    <span id='1' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>span 1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <br>
    <i ng-class='{"gamepad-red":tog==2}' class="fa fa-lg fa-gamepad"></i>
    <br/><span id='2' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>span 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.myclass {
  border: dotted pink 3px;
}

.gamepad-red {
  color: red;
}

.gamepad-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvLvg/286/

Comment: you must invert simple quotes and double quotes : `ng-class="{'myclass':tog==2}"`

Comment: I did not understand can you provide a jsfiddle? the code above is working, do u understand what I am trying to archive?

Comment: @noob-fella There's a fiddle link - at the bottom

Comment: yes the is the one I did provide :)

Comment: @noob-fella Oh, sorry :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS | Conditional Class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269916/angularjs-conditional-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: guys I am a noob, I cannot resolve this :(

Comment: Still a bit unclear: you want no border and a blue icon only when the span is clicked?

Comment: nope. when I click just in the Icon the Icon should be blue. :)

Comment: soo... like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/TmXfvNn2uqEFHrAN4Fgp

Comment: nope, I did Edit my question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved the effect of the span click to the wrapping div and used parent-child CSS to apply the red to the i element.

On click of the icon it triggers a separate boolean that controls a local class

iTog1 and iTog2 can be made to behave similar to tog if there can only be one selected

```css
.selected-gamepad > span {
  border: dotted pink 3px;
}

.selected-gamepad > i {
  color: red;
}

.gamepad-blue,
.selected-gamepad .gamepad-blue{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-class="{'selected-gamepad':tog==1}">
    <br>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-gamepad" ng-class="{'gamepad-blue': iTog1}" ng-click="iTog1 = !iTog1"></i>
    <span id='1' ng-click='tog=1'>span 1</span>
  </div>

  <div ng-class="{'selected-gamepad':tog==2}">
    <br>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-gamepad"  ng-class="{'gamepad-blue': iTog2}" ng-click="iTog2 = !iTog2"></i>
    <span id='2' ng-click='tog=2'>span 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, almost :), what I want to  do is when the control is click straight way change for blue color understand?  just apply that classses in the icon, I dont need border at span in that case, I was clear, I did edit my question. thank you again

Comment: Code updated. I think this has what you're looking for

Comment: yes, thank you so much, your answer will be accepted , thank you.

Comment: sorry me here again,  just the last thing, everything is working fine perfect, but when the icon is blue if I click in span the icon keeps blue and  will be possible when I click in span the icon change to red? thank you

Comment: Changing `ng-click='tog=2'` to `ng-click='tog=2; iTog2 = false;'` (and similar for iTog1) should do it. I would recommend moving the click functionality to the javascript controller if you're adding more complexity

Comment: perfect, works, u are the best, do u want update the question? anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry me again, its working  for span 2, but if I click in span 1 icon does not change for blue look: http://jsfiddle.net/zvLvg/288/